# Reproducir audio en angular

Tags: angular

Hola amigos quiero reproducir en el html un audio que se encuentras en una carpeta musica que esta en el mismo proyecto.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-audio',
  templateUrl: './audio.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class AudioComponent implements OnInit {

  audio = "./../../../musica/Hola.mp3";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Esta es la carpeta musica que contiene la musica
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cual es el contenido de tu `upload-image.component.html`. Debes incluirlo para saber como estás manipulando el audio.

Comment: eso es muy aparte quiero reproducir la musica que se encuentra en el directorio ./../../../musica/Hola.mp3 en el html

Comment: Y como se supone que sepamos lo que anda mal si tienes un problema pero no puedes decir donde?

Comment: Porfa que alguien me ayude

Comment: La razón por la que te pedimos ver el contenido del html es para saber si estas reproduciendo el audio con un elemento `<audio>` o programaticamente. La respuesta es diferente en cada caso.

Comment: y cual seria lo mas adecuando osea como reproduzco ese audio en el html, ahora el html esta vacio, por eso motivo quiero saber como reproduzco la musica que esta en es carpeta

Comment: Si quieres que no hayan controles en tu html y que al presionar un botón suene el audio deberías hacerlo en código. Si quieres que haya un elemento que le permita al usuario controlar la reproducción debes hacerlo en html

Comment: quiero que haya un elemento en el html que le permita al usuario controlar la reproducción, como lo hago

Answer (score 2):

Primero que todo, estás en un navegador así que tu servidor debe **servir** el fichero de audio también para que este esté disponible. Que esté en una carpeta de tu PC no significa nada pues cuando lo muevas a internet tu aplicación el fichero de audio seguirá en tu carpeta y no funcionará.

Dentro de la carpeta `src` hay otra carpeta `assets` donde se ponen las fotos y otros recursos, copia tu fichero para ahí y luego sólo tienes que añadir una etiqueta `<audio>` a tu html

```
<audio controls src='assets/Hola.mp3' type="audio/mp3">
    Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

Para hacerlo por código tienes que escribir esto en tu componente

```
export class AudioComponent {
    reproducir() {
        const audio = new Audio('assets/Hola.mp3');
        audio.play();
    }
}
```

En el template algún botón debe tener algo cómo esto `(click)="reproducir()"`

Cuando hagas un build tu fichero de audio también se incluirá al estar dentro de `assets` y funcionará tanto local como en internet.

Comment: Gracias me ayudo mucho, mi siguiente duda si tengo digamos la musica en una carpeta que no sea assets, digamos en el disco D, como ruta : D:\Hola.mp3, como puedo hacer en este caso

Comment: @ChrisAlexis Tienes que servirlos en internet. En el html solo tienes acceso a urls. Hay formas de usar ficheros locales pero solo si el usuario los selecciona usando un `<input>` de tipo `file`